# How would I create buttons so that they are in a line with all other buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show two buttons, `id="strength"` and `id="minion"`, when I click a button, `id="expandButton"`, and hide them when I click the button again. I want the two buttons created to be either side of the button that creates them. I tried putting them in a `<div>` together and adding a class with `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-around;`, but that just put the buttons next to each other above the button that created it. Ideally I need a way to move the two buttons down a bit so that all of the buttons are in a line.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eL8omg9x/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <button id="strength"><strong class="center">Strength</strong></button>
            <button id="expandButton" onclick="expandSkills()"><strong class="center">Expand</strong></button>
            <button id="minion"><strong class="center">Minion</strong></button>
        </div>
        <button id="xpButton"><strong class="center">Click Me!</strong></button>
     </div>
     <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#strength {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: green;
}
#expandButton {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: green;
}
#minion {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: green;
}
#xpButton {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: green;
}
.center {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function expandSkills() {
    let x = document.getElementById("strength");
    let y = document.getElementById("minion");
    let z = document.getElementById("skillsContainer");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "flex";
        y.style.display = "flex";
        z.style.justifyContent = "space-evenly";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.display = "none";
        z.style.justifyContent = "space-evenly";
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason they are _not_ all on the same "line", is that you have given the Expand button a margin-top of 100px, but for the Strength and Minion buttons, you did no such thing.

Comment: ^ It happens sometimes. Don't worry too much. Your question is clear with good code examples given.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob thank you, I'm just worried because it already warned that previous questions were poorly received and that I might be blocked from asking further questions.

Comment: question is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- adding margin-top during displaying of two buttons works
  or
- removing margin-top from expand button css also works
  Since for expand button margin-top is added

```js
function expandSkills() {
    let x = document.getElementById("strength");
    let y = document.getElementById("minion");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "flex";
        y.style.display = "flex";

        **//ADDING MARGIN TOP**
        y.style.margin = "100px 0 0 0";
        x.style.margin = "100px 0 0 0";
       
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

removed **skillsContainer** code as it was not defined in html